# UsedRange.Rows.Count not showing 0 despite clearing data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro to count the number of used rows in a sheet and print the count in a cell in another sheet

`Activesheet.Range("O9") = (Worksheets("Another_Sheet").UsedRange.Rows.Count) - 1`

every time the values in "Another_sheet" will be cleared 
`Worksheets("Another_Sheet").UsedRange.Clear`
and new set of rows will be printed and Activesheet.Range("O9") will hold the new value.

But the problem is, even if there are no values printed in "Another_Sheet", macro still prints number of rows that were there earlier and got cleared

I also tried `Worksheets("Another_Sheet").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row`

Comment: This post will show you best method  [Post Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).

Comment: As a Stop gap, I am check if A1 of "Another_Sheet" has value and count used rows only if A1 is not empty

Comment: You need to save your workbook and reopen it, or else `rows.count` will count the rows in the used range that contained data.